# Facebook conversion pixel - verified but not counted

Tags: javascript, facebook, ads

**Short version:**
I have a Conversion Pixel  which is being triggered, but the problem is that it's not reported in the conversion report.

**Long version:**
I've implemented Facebook's [conversion pixel](https://www.facebook.com/help/435189689870514) in my site.
I can see that the pixel is verified in the Power Manager. 
See the pixel 'Leads' pixel in the screenshot below.

[image]

However, in the campaign report, I can see the 'Leads' count remains zero.

[image]

It's important to note that the site is not a regular static webpage. It's a dynamic page. The Leads pixel is **triggered by javascript**, as described in this [blog post](http://flashfotoincblog.com/2013/04/25/using-facebook-conversion-tracking-pixels-in-a-dynamic-web-application/).
Also, there is **a second tracking pixel on this page**, the one labelled 'Key Page Views'. The Page View pixel is implemented using the standard method, with a js snippet in the header. As you can see the second pixel is triggered and reported just fine.

Comment: Did you get this solved ?

Comment: Not sure, it was a long time ago.
Today, I'd look into triggering the pixel via Google Tag Manager.